# Set state from content of another item in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to setState of `order` to be the content of `catalog` only if it's `true`, I guess I need to make a function that always listen if the state of `order` changes.

This is my state

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    catalog: [
      {
        photo: 'https://via.placeholder.com/164x168',
        title: 'FirstItem',
        description: 'Fugiat nulla incididunt laborum et esse adipisicing esse aliquip.',
        size_m: { size: 'M', price: 5000, id: 'FTM', selectedIndicator: '', isSelected: false },
        size_l: { size: 'L', price: 8000, id: 'FTL', selectedIndicator: '', isSelected: false },
        size_xl: { size: 'XL', price: 10000, id: 'FTXL', selectedIndicator: '', isSelected: false },
      },
      {
        photo: 'https://via.placeholder.com/164x168',
        title: 'SecondItem',
        description: 'Fugiat nulla incididunt laborum et esse adipisicing esse aliquip.',
        size_m: { size: 'M', price: 5000, id: 'SCRM', selectedIndicator: '', isSelected: false },
        size_l: { size: 'L', price: 8000, id: 'SCRL', selectedIndicator: '', isSelected: false },
        size_xl: { size: 'XL', price: 10000, id: 'SCXL', selectedIndicator: '', isSelected: false },
      },
    ],
    order: []
  }
}
```

Example: In case of `size_m` of first item and `size_l` of second item in `catalog` change `isSelected` to `true`, `order` state should update to

```
order: [
  {
    size_m: { size: 'M', price: 5000, id: 'FTM', selectedIndicator: '', isSelected: true },
    size_l: { size: 'L', price: 8000, id: 'SCRL', selectedIndicator: '', isSelected: true }
  }
]
```

This is my handler function

```
  setOrder = () => {
    const { catalog } = this.state
    let catalogOrder = []
    catalog.map(item => {
      if(item.size_m.isSelected) {
        catalogOrder = [item]
      }
      return this.setState({order: catalogOrder})
    })
  }
```

Comment: `item.size_m.isSelected` why not for other sizes?

Comment: @RahulDwivedi actually it should apply for all of the sizes, sorry my bad...

Comment: What you trying to achieve is ambiguous!
What you mean by this:
"In case of size_m of first item and size_l of second item in catalog change isSelected to true" ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your handler function to something like this. Use `forEach` instead of `map`, take the `setState` call out of the callback, and remove `return` from the last line:

```
setOrder = () => {
  const { catalog } = this.state
  let catalogOrder = []
  catalog.forEach(item => {
    if(item.size_m.isSelected) {
      catalogOrder.push(item)
    }
  })
  this.setState({order: catalogOrder})
}
```

The `map` method maps a modification of the elements in the original array onto a new array -- for example, you want to multiply every number in your array by 3 -- and I don't think that's what you're trying to do here. [Read more about `map` in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

**EDIT 1:** The above will not solve your problem entirely, as your code currently only checks for medium sizes. I think one way to achieve what you're trying to do is to make a new property under each `catalog` item that keeps track of the size that is selected, so for example:

```
this.state = {
    catalog: [
      {
        photo: 'https://via.placeholder.com/164x168',
        title: 'FirstItem',
        description: 'Fugiat nulla incididunt laborum et esse adipisicing esse aliquip.',
        selectedSize: '',   // this can hold whatever object or reference you need
        ...
      },
        ...
    ]
...
}
```

**EDIT 2:** To trigger the `setOrder` handler appropriately, take a look at [this article](https://dev.to/cesareferrari/how-to-use-componentdidupdate-in-react-30en) for watching changes in a state with `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: I tried both options but no success, I think there is some error or special way to call setOrder function so it always listening for a change in the state

Comment: Take a look at this article for watching changes in a state with `componentDidUpdate()` https://dev.to/cesareferrari/how-to-use-componentdidupdate-in-react-30en

Comment: @Rezpo where are you calling `setOrder ` from?

Comment: @Rezpo There's no special way. `setOrder` is a normal method just like any other which can update the state which in turn will re-render the component.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.

```
 setOrder = () => {
    const { catalog } = this.state


     var catalogOrder = [];
        catalog.forEach(i=>{
          if(i.size_m.isSelected){
             catalogOrder.push(i.size_m);
           }else if(i.size_xl.isSelected ){
             catalogOrder.push(i.size_s);
           }else if(i.size_l.isSelected){
             catalogOrder.push(i.size_l);
            }
        });
        this.setState({order: catalogOrder});

      }
```

Comment: May I ask why you are using `push` and `map`?

Comment: `map` is for iterating through the `catalog` item. `push` is to push the intended items. You may do like this too: `catalogOrder = [...catalogOrder, ...i]` if you don't wanna push.

Comment: This would work, but I think `forEach` would be less redundant because you don't need the `map` function to create a new array. I also like your spread operator option.

Comment: Yup, I agree `forEach` part. Since we're not creating a new array, map can be replaced with `forEach`